# Simplifying a double integral to a single integral

Tags: integration, stochastic-processes, exponential-function

In a recent [cross-validated post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/226657/variance-of-the-integral-of-a-stochastic-process) a comment was left by Dilip Sarwate that stated that the following double integral:

$$\int_0^L \int_0^L \rho(t-u)dudt$$

Could be simplified to the following single integral:

$$\int_{-L}^{L} \rho(s)(L-|s|)\,\mathrm ds$$

Where $\rho(t-u)$ is the correlation function of a stochastic process. Mathematica gives both integrals the same value for a correlation function of the form:
$$\rho(t-u) = \exp\left(-\pi\left(\frac{t-u}{\theta}\right)^2\right) = \rho(s) = \exp\left(-\pi\left(\frac{s}{\theta}\right)^2\right)$$

Can you explain why this simplification is possible and how the double integral simplifies to the single integral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align*}
\int_0^L\int_0^L\rho(t-u)dudt &= \int_0^L\int_{t-L}^t \rho(s) ds dt\\
&=\int_0^L\int_0^t \rho(s) ds dt + \int_0^L\int_{t-L}^0 \rho(s) ds dt\\
&=\int_0^L\int_s^L \rho(s) dt ds + \int_{-L}^0\int_0^{L+s} \rho(s) dt ds\\
&=\int_0^L\rho(s)(L-s) ds + \int_{-L}^0\rho(s) (L+s) ds\\
&=\int_0^L\rho(s)(L-|s|) ds + \int_{-L}^0\rho(s) (L-|s|) ds\\
&=\int_{-L}^L\rho(s)(L-|s|) ds.
\end{align*}