# Is integration by parts used in this equality?

Tags: indefinite-integrals, convolution

The starting point is this convolution
$$
\frac{\partial v_0}{\partial G}(t) = \int_0^t v_G(\xi)  \Psi^{(0)}_G(t-\xi)  \,d\xi.
$$
Applying the product rule for differentiation
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^2v_0}{\partial G^2}(t) &= \int_0^t \left\{ \frac{\partial v_G}{\partial G}(\xi) \Psi^{(0)}_G(t-\xi) + v_G(\xi) \frac{\partial \Psi^{(0)}_G}{\partial G}(t - \xi)\right\} d\xi  \\&= 2 \int_0^t \left\{ \int_0^{\xi} v_G(\eta) \Psi^{(G)}_G(\xi - \eta)\,d\eta \right\} \Psi^{(0)}_G(t-\xi) \,d\xi
\end{align*}

Can anyone help on how the double convolution appears? What step is needed to understand the last equality?

EDIT:
This is the source of the equality
[image]

Comment: It's definitely not by parts, because you're integrating w.r.t. $\xi$ but differentiating w.r.t. $G.$ Is it the case that, from your first convolution, $\displaystyle \frac{\partial v_G}{\partial G}(t) = \int_0^t v_G(\xi)  \Psi^{(G)}_G(t-\xi)  \,d\xi?$ It's not inherently obvious why that should be, so I'm thinking there is some additional context here that might elucidate. Might it also be the case that, from your first convolution, you can get a handle on $\dfrac{\partial\Psi_G^{(0)}}{\partial G}(t-\xi)?$ That might help.

Comment: @Adrian Keister I'm no expert and thought that maybe integration by parts could be involved as it seems differentiation is replaced by integration. I have provided the source of the equation/equality which should provide any context if it is needed.

Comment: @Adrian Keister It is not easy to describe in full detail how that convolution is derived but its origin is from network theory where the derivative of an output ($v_0$) with respect to a parameter $G$ can be computed from the input to $G$ which is $v_G$ and then another input $\Psi_G$ from another network by convolution of the two. But I was hoping all this background is not need to derive that last equality.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for posting the additional context. There's a trick for reducing the number of integrations, and it introduces a convolution via changing the order of integration. I wonder if that's being used here, in reverse. Reference: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1888102/simplifying-a-double-integral-to-a-single-integral.

Comment: It looks like it has something to do with the Laplace Transform convolution property: $$\mathcal{L}[(f * g)(t)]=\mathcal{L}\left[\int_0^t f(\tau) g(t-\tau)\,d\tau\right]=F(s)\cdot G(s).$$ These are deep waters, though, and I think you're going to have to go back to the original paper and see how the derivative with respect to the conductance is carried out.

Comment: @AdrianKeister I think I got the first part of it. Since it is given that $$\frac{\partial v_0}{\partial G}(t) = \int_0^t v_G(\xi)  \Psi^{(0)}_G(t-\xi)  \,d\xi.$$ then $$\frac{\partial v_G}{\partial G}(t) = \int_0^t v_G(\xi)  \Psi^{(G)}_G(t-\xi)  \,d\xi.$$.

Comment: So it seems all pieces come together if $$v_G(\xi) \frac{\partial \Psi^{(0)}_G}{\partial G}(t - \xi) = \int_0^{\xi} v_G(\eta) \Psi^{(G)}_G(\xi - \eta)\,d\eta  \Psi^{(0)}_G(t-\xi)$$ but how that $v_G$ should go under the integral sign I don't know. I think somehow $\frac{\partial \Psi^{(0)}_G}{\partial G}(t - \xi) $ can be rewritten in some clever way.

Comment: @AdrianKeister If you compile your comments into an answer I will accept it